# Logitech c270 camera not taking pictures on linux(ubuntu) with open-cv python

Tags: python, opencv, logitech

`Logitech c270` camera not taking pictures on `linux(ubuntu)` with open-cv python. I have also tried adding delays, installing drivers in the terminal, and almost everything but still takes a blacked-out picture.
*also with `index(0)` it takes photo within like 1 sec but with `index(3)` i.e my logitech camera it takes the blacked-out photo in milliseconds!

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(3)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

# Read a frame from the camera
ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret:
    cv2.imwrite("photo.jpg", frame)

# Release the camera and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- I tried an older camera same model like 2 months old code works there, I have bought two new ones but it occurs in both of them.
- I tried on C920 logitech the code works there also.
- I have 4 of them C270, opened two both had the fault, I think all of them would have it, so I can't risk opening all.
- I have also tried adding delays, installing drivers in the terminal, and almost everything but still takes blacked-out picture.
- *also with index (0) it takes a photo within like 1 sec but with index (3) i.e my logitech camera it takes the blacked-out photo in milliseconds!

Comment: Does the camera work when you use linux webcam tools like cheese (cheese is usually pre-installed)?

Comment: You have 3 cameras. You can do this cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1) and so on.

Comment: You have multiple cameras, so to minimize complexity and confusion, I highly recommend using unique paths in ``/dev/v4l/`` subdirectory (see my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184335/1510289) instead of the enumerations you're using currently.